# Laravel: issue updating project table with an array of selected products

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an app where a user can select multiple products from a project. The problem is when I try to update the project, I get the following error: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::project does not exist.

A user should be able to delete and edit a product from a project:
[image: edit project]

ProjectController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
        
        $project->update($request->all());

        $products = Product::find($request->products);

        $products->project()->associate($products);

        // $products->project()->upsert($project);


        //$products = Product::find($request->products);

        //$products->project()->saveMany($project);
        

    }
```

Project.php

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

Product.php

```
public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
```

Comment: Which line are you getting that error on?

Comment: @aynber Line: 113 and 119 in projectcontroller.php

Comment: Which are? You don't tell us which lines are which.

Comment: @aynber Line 119 is this code: $products->project()->associate($products);